# ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW only working on first 15 rows?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to get a rolling total per account in our system. So each transaction add/subtracts line by line

I'm Attempting to use the unbound preceding functionality in SQL 2016.

, SUM(isnull(Value,0.00)) OVER(ORDER BY AccountNo ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Total

Currently this works up until line 15 then it just starts a rolling total of every transaction, I've tried varying combinations of the Unbounded function but always get the same result?

[image]

Comment: you need PARTITION BY inthere, you are not 'breaking' on changes of accountno - when 221 changes to 230, it was just a coincidence that the balance had dropped to zero at that very point, so you did appear then to be getting the rolling sum for 230

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a rolling sum per *account*, then you should be using this syntax:

```
SELECT
    AccountNo,
    TrackingValue,
    mk,
    SUM(TrackingValue) OVER (PARTITION BY AccountNo ORDER BY mk) AS RollingSum
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    AccountNo,
    mk;
```

Note that the default window for `SUM()`, when used as an analytic function, is already `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`, so you do not need to specify this explicitly if you just want an unbounded rolling sum.